# SSIS: enrich query and table with input file as base

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2

I need to extract data from a DB2 database to a SQL Server. I need to create my query based on a Excel file I have 176 records, which I need to create repeating queries & put in SQL server
So for example;

I have an Excel with a Number, From date, To date, and a Country
So the query should use these information from the records

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test
WHERE Number = excel.Number1 AND Date BETWEEN excel.fromDate1 AND excel.toDate1 AND Country = excel.country1
```

And then another query with

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test
WHERE Number = excel.Number2 AND Date BETWEEN excel.fromDate2 AND excel.toDate2 AND Country = excel.country2
```

Etc...

How should I do something like this in SSIS?

If needed I can put the DB2 and Excel data in MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed with the following approach:

- Extract data rows from Excel and put it into SSIS Object Variable
- Proceed with a Foreach loop to get each row from the Object Variable, parsing Object Variable to separate variables
- Inject variable values into SQL Select command with Expressions
- Perform Data Flow task based on SQL command, transform and put it into the target

Overall, your task seems to be feasible, but requires some knowledge on parsing Object Variable in Foreach Loop, and writing Variable Expressions.